# How to create a type that will accept any primitive type or combination of primitive types

Tags: typescript

I want to create a type that will accept only "simple" data (usecase: log metadata). Its definition would be recursive. I would like to accept:

- Primitive types
- Any object with string keys and this type as values
- Any array of this type

So far I did this:

```js
type Primitive = string | number | boolean | null

type LogMetadata = {
  readonly [key: string]: Primitive | LogMetadata | Array<LogMetadata>
}

function log(message:string, LogMetadata) {
  // implementation irrelevant to the question
}
```

Then I try to use this API like this

```js
interface Person {
  firstName: string
  lastName: string
}

const person: Person = { firstName:'John', lastName: 'Doe' }
const sessionId = 'test'

log('Hello', { person, sessionId })
```

It doesn't work for the person field because I get this error:

`Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type Person`

How can I modify the signature of the log function and/or the definition of the LogMetadata type to get it working, but still restrict calls to simple types build only using primitives, object and arrays (excluding functions, symbols, and other things that might not work well in logs).

Comment: Your code isn't quite a [mre].  The error you're getting is presumably that `Person` is an `interface` (as opposed to a type alias of an anonymous object type) so could you please define `Person` for us in the code?  (And `Primitive`, while you're at it?)

Comment: btw this is probably [ms/TS#15300](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15300) and the easiest way around this is to just sidestep interfaces like `const myMetadata: LogMetadata = {person: {...person}}`.  There are other workarounds, I guess, also.  Still waiting for a [mre] though.

Comment: @jcalz, thanks for the pointers. Indeed I didn't provide a reproductible example, sorry for this, this is fixed now. What would be the other workaround you mentionned ? That would be great if I could avoid duplicating objects without a good reason... thanks a lot !

Comment: [Here](https://tsplay.dev/Wk09jw) are the various approaches.  Either you use the spread method as mentioned in ms/TS#15300, or you rewrite `LogMetadata` as a recursive generic constraint `CheckLogMetadata<T>`.  Let me know if you want me to write up either or both of those.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is this, it uses conditional types. Primitive is a union of whatever you might consider a primitive type. Then logMetaData is going to be generic, it has each key the same as the type T that is passed in.

Each key's value is a conditional type, we do the following checks.

If T[key] is an object, then we want the metaData for that object.

Otherwise, check if T[key] is an Array, if it is, make the value an Array of metaData for that array's type.

Finally, if it's none of those it has to be primitive.

```
type Primitive = boolean | number | string | undefined;

type LogMetadata<T> = {
  [key in keyof T]: 
    T[key] extends Object ? 
    LogMetadata<T[key]> : 
    T[key] extends Array<unknown> ?
    Array<LogMetadata<T[key][number]>> :
    Primitive;
}

type Person = {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  pets: string[],
  friends: Person[];
}

const person: Person = { firstName:'John', lastName: 'Doe', pets: ["dog", "cat"], friends: [
  {
    firstName: "Billy",
    lastName: "Bob",
    pets: [],
    friends: [],
  }
] }

const myMetadata: LogMetadata<Person> = { ...person }
```